# DataGridView's UserDeletingRow method is called 3 times by itself

Tags: c#, datagridview

I created new windows form application with DataGridView. This is the only form it has.
The MessageBox in DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow method is called 3 times. I rly need to understand why is that. The obvious problem is DataSource, because adding rows manually to dataGridView, method is **not** unnecessarily called 3 times.

I also found out that if I put this line of code

```
dataGridView1.RowsRemoved += new DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventHandler(DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow);
```

after

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

everything works fine and method DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow is not called.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.RowsRemoved += new DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventHandler(DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow);

            var dt = new DataTable("myTableName");
            dt.Columns.Add("myColumnName");
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 123 });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: it's hard to understand this because it involves the **internal implementation** of `DataSource = ...` (the `setter` of `DataSource`). If you don't use `DataSource`, everything will be *normal*. It happens to the `initialization` of `DataSource` only, after the assignment for `DataSource`, you can try adding rows to and removing rows from `DataTable` (the underlying source), you will see that the `RowsAdded` and `RowsRemoved` will be fired with the correct number of times.

Comment: @King It's very annoying... The number of times the method is called is totally unpredictable. I created this application just to get some answers. In my real application, the method is called 2 times, not 3, can you beliave it? srsly...

Comment: Not really, the problem is we don't understand well the implementation of the `DataSource setter`, if you set `AllowUserToAddRows = false`, the number of time firing would be decreased to 2. However as I said, that happens only when you initialize the `DataSource`, you can use some `flag` to exclude this initial special case and then, everything would work OK.

Comment: @King Well, flag would be a solution, indeed, but I tought there is a better way. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just had the same problem and this is how I fixed it:

```
protected override void OnUserDeletedRow(DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUserDeletedRow(e);

    //You're code here
}
```

I used override on the DataGridView function OnUserDeletedRow, called the base function and added the code I wanted to trigger.

This function only triggered once and solved my problem, you can also override other function like this as an alternative to listening to an event.

Good luck.

Comment: @Tvde1 Sorry i don't know what you mean.